# Expressão Regular para números entre determinados intervalos

Tags: regex

Precisei fazer uma expressão regular onde só aceite os números de **11-14, 21-24, 31-34**.

Fiz a seguinte expressão regular:

```
^\A[11-14|21-24|31-34]{2}$
```

Está funcionado, porém por que está aceitando também os números de **41-44** ?
Não consigo entender e nem corrigir.

Comment: Já testou `^\A[1-3][1-4]$`?

Comment: Perfeito, funcionou certinho e bem mais simples. Eu nunca fiz Expressão Regular na minha vida, primeira vez, procurei hoje sobre o assunto.
Muito obrigado.

Comment: Carlos e @anonimo - só vale lembrar que usar `^` e `\A` juntos não faz muito sentido (conforme explico na minha resposta abaixo - só não detalhei mais porque não é o foco da pergunta)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simples, todos os caracteres que você coloca entre colchetes são na verdade uma [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html): uma lista de caracteres que devem ser aceitos.

Por exemplo, `[abc]` signfica "a letra `a`, ou `b`, ou `c`" (qualquer uma delas). E você também pode especificar intervalos: `[a-f]` é "qualquer letra de `a` a `f`".

Sendo assim, `[11-14|21-24|31-34]` na verdade significa "o dígito `1`, ou um dígito de 1 a 4 (`1-4`), ou o caractere `|`, ou o dígito `2`, etc".

E como você colocou o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `{2}`, a regex aceita 2 ocorrências disso (ou seja, 2 caracteres que sejam 1, ou um dígito de 1 a 4, ou `|`, etc). Por isso ela aceita 44, e até mesmo `||` seria aceito ([pode testar](https://regex101.com/r/F13Qv4/1/)).

Sendo assim, a expressão correta seria `^[1-3][1-4]$` (o primeiro caractere é um dígito de 1 a 3, e o segundo é um dígito de 1 a 4).

**Obs:** Repare que removi o [atalho `\A`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html#az) pois me parece redundante, já que o `^` indica o início da string, e o `\A` também (a diferença se dá se você usa o modo multi-linha, no qual o `^` também considera o início de uma linha, mas aí você teria que escolher entre um ou outro de qualquer jeito, pois ambos na mesma expressão - um logo depois do outro - não faz sentido).

Comment: Perfeito @hkotsubo, obrigado pelas explicação, agora entendi o conceito, achei que colocando com o | seria como um "ou"... e funcionou mesmo o `||` você tem razão... rsrs
Funcionou perfeitamente como falou, aliás, como o colega anterior comentou funcionou no regex101 mas não funcionou nos Forms do Google, onde vou usar nesse caso. Ao remover o `\A`, funcionou perfeitamente.
Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @CarlosHenriqueNevesCHNeves O `|` significa "ou", mas só se estiver fora dos colchetes. Dentro dos colchetes os meta-caracteres "perdem seus poderes" e se tornam caracteres "normais".

Comment: Entendi @hkotsubo obrigado por mais esse esclarecimento. Não sabia que havia diferença estando dentro dos colchetes. Obrigado.